# How to calculate MDE w/ no. of visitors and conversion rate only?

Tags: statistics, ab-testing, abtest

If you go to this website, you can get MDE w/ only no. of visitors and conversion rate.

https://www.abtasty.com/sample-size-calculator/

I was wondering what is the formular of this MDE.
by using this formular I could also set best & worst Conversion rate cases for A/B Testing I think.

But I think I need to know if it is reasonable or not before using it.

If there is anyone who knows this formular, please let me know.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEdXA.png)

I tried to find out what is the formaular, but MDE normally is the one I need to set by ROI or others. so I couldn't get the formular by research